# T-SQL - Update list of customers CustomerID (Alphanumeric) with next in sequence

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of new customers in an old legacy system which I need to calculate and update the CustomerID of which is Alphanumeric (5 letters 3 numbers). The legacy system already has a list of customerIDs. I want to update the new customersIDs in line with the existing sequence.

There may also be a 5 letter id which doesn't already exist in the list and would therefore start at 001.

I have the 5 letters for each new customer within a field. I just need to update with the next in sequence.

For example:

**ExistingCustomerIDs**

```
ALPHA001
ALPHA002
COLUM001
COLUM002
TESTI001
TESTI002
TESTI003
TESTI004
```

**New Customers Table only contains the beginning 5 letters.**

```
ALPHA   (Should become ALPHA003)
ALPHA   (Should become ALPHA004)
ALPHA   (Should become ALPHA005)
COLUM   (Should become COLUM003)
COLUM   (Should become COLUM004)
TESTI   (Should become TESTI005)
DANIE   (Should become DANIE001)
DANIE   (Should become DANIE002)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate new numbers, you just need to start the count with the previous max available from existing IDs.

Setup:

```
DECLARE @ExistingIDs TABLE (OldCustomerID VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @ExistingIDs (OldCustomerID)
VALUES
    ('ALPHA001'),
    ('ALPHA002'),
    ('COLUM001'),
    ('COLUM002'),
    ('TESTI001'),
    ('TESTI002'),
    ('TESTI003'),
    ('TESTI004')

DECLARE @NewIds TABLE (NewCustomerID VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @NewIds (NewCustomerID)
VALUES 
    ('ALPHA'),('ALPHA'),('ALPHA'),
    ('COLUM'),('COLUM'),
    ('TESTI'),
    ('DANIE'),('DANIE')
```

Solution:

```
;WITH PreviousMax AS
(
    SELECT
        Letters = LEFT(E.OldCustomerID, 5),
        LatestNumber = MAX(CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(E.OldCustomerID, 3)))
    FROM
        @ExistingIDs AS E
    GROUP BY
        LEFT(E.OldCustomerID, 5)
)
SELECT
    N.NewCustomerID,
    UpdatedNewCustomerID = N.NewCustomerID + 
        RIGHT(
            '00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), ISNULL(P.LatestNumber, 0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY N.NewCustomerID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))),
            3)
FROM
    @NewIds AS N
    LEFT JOIN PreviousMax AS P ON N.NewCustomerID = P.Letters
```

Result:

```
NewCustomerID   UpdatedNewCustomerID
ALPHA           ALPHA003
ALPHA           ALPHA004
ALPHA           ALPHA005
COLUM           COLUM003
COLUM           COLUM004
DANIE           DANIE001
DANIE           DANIE002
TESTI           TESTI005
```

Comment: Works a treat. Fantasic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  You can do this by extracting the last value for each customer id from the existing customers.  Then adding this to an enumeration for the new customers:

```
with e as (
      select left(customerId, length(customerId) - 3) as base, max(right(customerId, 3)) + 0 as lastnum
      from existing e
      group by left(customerId, length(customerId) - 3)
     ),
     nc as (
      select customerId, row_number() over (partition by customerId order by customerId) as seqnum
      from newcustomers
     )
update nc
    set nc.customerId = nc.customerId + right('000' + convert(varchar(255), seqnum + base))
    from nc join
         e
         on nc.customerId = e.base;
```